# sqlalchemy joinedload query can not make counting

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables `table_a` and `table_b`. `table_b.code_b` is the foreign key of the `table_a`

```
table_a
code_a, val
-----------
aaa,100

table_b
code_b, name
------------
aaa, name1
```

I want to get this result with joining two tables:

```
table_result
code_a,val,name
---------------
aaa,100,name1
```

The following is the Python code:

```
class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table_a'
    code_a = Column(String(20), ForeignKey("table_b.code_b"), primary_key=True)
    val = Column(Float)
    b = relationship("B", backref=backref('table_b'))


class B(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table_b'
    code_b = Column(String(20), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100))
    a = relationship("A", backref="table_a")

where_str = "code_b='aaa'"
q = A.query.options(joinedload_all(A.b)).filter(text(where_str))

rows1 = [i.serialize for i in q.all()] # CORRECT
rows2 = [i.serialize for i in q.paginate(1,10,False)] # ERROR
```

If I just query all to get `rows1`, it's correct result. However, I will get error with running `rows2`:
**DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00904: "code_b"**

I debug this error with print the SQL statement:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_1
FROM (SELECT "table_a".code_a AS "table_a_code_a", 
FROM "table_a"
WHERE code_b = 'aaa') anon_1
```

It's clear that two tables are **NOT** joined.

But, If just `q.all()`, SQL statement will be:

```
SELECT "table_a".code_a AS "table_a_code_a", 
FROM "table_a" LEFT JOIN "table_b"
WHERE code_b = 'aaa'
```

This is correct.

So, How to get the right result when making the pagination.

---

**EDIT1:**

**Q: Why I use `where_str`?**

A: In HTML page, I use the query builder(http://querybuilder.js.org/) to get query filter(maybe complicated). So, it's convenient to pass to SQLAlchemy query filer.

There are any better ways to implement this?

---

**EDIT2:**
Solution:

```
q = A.query.join(A.b).options(contains_eager(A.b)).filter(text(where_str))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
where_str = "code_b='aaa'"
q = A.query.options(joinedload_all(A.b)).filter(text(where_str))
```

How is SQLAlchemy supposed to know that the `code_b` in your `where_str` is supposed to refer to table B?

Try:

```
q = A.query.join(A.b).filter(B.code_b == "aaa")
```

If you also need to perform a `joinedload`, do this:

```
q = A.query.join(A.b).options(contains_eager(A.b)).filter(B.code_b == "aaa")
```

Comment: @seizetheday Just because you need to pass the filter in from the frontend doesn't mean you need to use a `text` construct. Regardless, that you're using a `text` construct is not the problem per se; the problem is your use of `joinedload` instead of `.join`.